# Issues with passport password reset in nodejs

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I sign up and it generates the hash and salt. I login and everything works properly. My program was missing a reset password feature. So I added a forgot password which sends you a token in your email, then I use the token to change my password which updates the hash and salt to encrypted stuff. Then when I try to login with the new password it says password is incorrect.

`hello` is the password

```js
var newSalt = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
var newPassword = crypto.pbkdf2Sync('hello', newSalt, 10000, 64, 'sha512').toString('base64');

User.update({
  myhash: newPassword,
  mysalt: newSalt
},
{
  where: {
    token: 'VUQKPIElnpITEeBJVsuyGBE1EX7RaxPRD0BblhZqYrUjHH3fXcz3yiFc+fHtm0PtOR/7UCSAdlEoUbdtTlgS7g=='
  }
});
```

Endpoints

```js
// SIGNUP
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  User.register(new User({username: req.body.username, email: req.body.email}), req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.send(err);
    }
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
      return res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login");
    });
  });
});

// CREATE TOKEN
router.post('/forgot-password', async function(req, res) {
  var email = await User.findOne({where: { email: req.body.email}});
  //create random token
  var fpSalt = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('base64');
  await User.update(
    {expiration: expireDate},
    {where: {email: req.body.email}}
  )
});
```

Comment: Show us the code where you set up password during sign-up.
And also possible the code where you genereate and save the token.

Comment: @libik I just updated it, you can check it out

Comment: I need to see how logic in here looks like `User.register`

Comment: In my whole codebase only that line is `User.register` which is part of passportjs, I think.